# How to develop an image scanner(text recognizer) for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My client requirement is to develop an image scanner(text recognizer) for iphone.I have googled but got nothing.
Please guide me from where I start or some document or some code or link.

Comment: You might find the [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) project helpful.

Comment: Please provide solution if you got anything for this, i am also working on this now

Answer (score 3):

you can try this - http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/

Here are some open source -

http://robertcarlsen.net/dev/pocket-ocr

http://sites.google.com/site/olipion/cross-compilation/tesseract-ocr